# Can I use firebase to pass data from an Android app to ASP.NET (Web Forms) and vice versa?

Tags: android, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, firebase

I would like to know if I am able to use Firebase to pass data from an Android App to a ASP.NET web application(Web Forms) and vice versa (Web to an Android app).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use `HttpURLConnection` to pass from the App to a form?

Somthing like this will POST JSON data to a URL of your choice and then read back any response.

```
        HttpURLConnection conn   = null;
        StringBuilder     result = new StringBuilder();
        JSONObject        jObj   = null;

        // request method is POST
        try {

            URL urlObj = new URL();


            conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(data.getBytes().length);
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.connect();

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(data);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            //Receive the response from the server
            InputStream    in     = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String         line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is it some kind of Web API ? 
If yes,then can i learn Web API without knowing WCF